# Turbolinks, Rails, back button, footer from other source

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, coffeescript, turbolinks

I have an issue with turbolinks. When I click a 'back' button in browser there is one more footer appends.

In `application.html.slim`:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title
      - unless content_for(:title).present?
        | Some text...
      - else
        == yield :title
    meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    - if admin_admin_signed_in?
      = stylesheet_link_tag    'cms/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
      = javascript_include_tag 'cms/application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

I load a footer from the other source (`application.coffee`):

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
    $('footer').get(0).innerHTML = ''
    for src in ['//other_site.com/goc/us/other_site.com/responsive.js', '//other_site.com/footer-builder.js']
      s = document.createElement('script')
      s.async = true
      s.src = src
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild s
```

Thanks for attention in advance!

Comment: its cause because turbolink cache your content

Comment: @uzaif Thanks for the answer! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @uzaif I added more information about the problem

Comment: You can user `Turbolikns.clearCache()` method to clear cache or you can clear cache on rails side

Comment: @uzaif Thanks a lot!

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: @uzaif I'm not sure turbolinks work properly now (didn't make profiling yet), but at least problem has gone, so thank you! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @uzaif said you should put `Turbolinks.clearCache()`into your `.js file` for particular dom element or even page in similar situations. In my case I added the following peace of code this way:

`application.coffee`:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('footer').get(0).innerHTML = ''
  for src in ['//other_site.com/goc/us/other_site.com/responsive.js', '//other_site.com/footer-builder.js']
    s = document.createElement('script')
    s.async = true
    s.src = src
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild s
  Turbolinks.clearCache()
```

Keep in mind it can reduce speed of page loading so make application profiling to be sure

Comment: you have a typo, Turbolikns.clearCache() should be Turbolinks.clearCache()

Answer (score 1):

By clearing the cache (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398711/783009) you''ll be missing out on some of the performance benefits that Turbolinks offers.

@uzaif is correct in that the page is being cached. Here is what is happening:

1. Page 1 loads
2. Footer is loaded from other source
3. User clicks on a link to page 2
4. Turbolinks caches the page
5. Page 2 loads
6. User presses Back
7. Turbolinks loads the cached page (with the footer)
8. Footer is loaded again from other source :/

If you are adding HTML to a page on every page load, the idiomatic approach is to "teardown" the effects of any scripts on `turbolinks:before-cache`. It's a little tricky to write code for this without seeing what the footer scripts do, but the general idea is:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  # load your footer…

$(document).on 'turbolinks:before-cache', ->
  # teardown your footer
```

For more information on this, see here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#preparing-the-page-to-be-cached

Alternatively, if the footer doesn't change between page loads, you may wish to only load the content once (e.g. on `$(document).ready`), then keep it between page loads. To do this, you'll need to give the footer an ID, and a `data-turbolinks-permanent` attribute. As long as the footer with the ID is in every response from the server, the footer content with be maintained. For more on this, see here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

Comment: Absolutely correct! I tried ```turbolinks:before-cache``` but with no success, anyway thanks a lot for nice point and full answer!

Comment: You are welcome! If you could show how the HTML differs before and after the footer loads, I might be able to help further :)

Comment: awesome! Thank you one more time! :)